# git pull --rebase for a specific folder/file

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

I only want to rebase one folder.

Is it possible to do something like

```
git pull --rebase origin/master path/to/folder/or/file.txt
```

and only that path will be updated?

Comment: *I only want to rebase one folder.* No. Rebasing only makes sense for commits, not for individual files/folders. What you may want to do, instead, is check out the version of `path/to/folder/or/file.txt` in your working tree, stage the file and make a new commit on your local `master` branch.

Comment: @jub0bs it makes total sense if the commits are logically grouped by a path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quick answer is "no".

The longer answer depends on what you are trying to accomplish, and whether or not you have any changes to any of the files/folders you want to rebase, and what if any history you are interested in showing.

If you have no changes on your branch, and you just want to grab the latest file from origin/master and put it in your working directory, and you don't want there to be any 'history' of what happened, then you could do

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file.txt
```

For anything more complicated than that it gets ugly fast.

Answer (score 5):

My idea for this is something along the lines:

```
git cherry-pick $(git log --oneline HEAD..origin/master -- path/to/something | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac| xargs echo)
```

[Edit]
As suggested by @CervEd there is a more straightforward way

```
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list HEAD..origin/master -- path)
```

Comment: I would suggest `git cherry-pick $(git rev-list HEAD..origin/master -- path)`

Comment: ofc it's not going to `cherry-pick` only from that path but also the entire commit, which may include other paths. Creating your own rebase todo file may be more appropriate

Comment: Good simplification CervEd. If you want i can edit the answer or you answer yourself as i think your solution is superior.
Extra, if you only want to changes from the specific paths then you just git checkout <path> -- HASH

Comment: I don't think it deserves a separate answer, better to modify this one, assuming it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on master branch, i think the closest to what you want is something like this:

```
git checkout -b tmp_rebase_branch master
git pull --rebase
git checkout master
git checkout tmp_rebase_branch -- path/to/folder/or/file.txt
```

Rebase the whole lot on a temporary branch and then checkout only the part you want to move to your master branch. You will get the content of the rebase of that path/to/folder/or/file.txt but there will not be an actual rebase of your master branch. As a rebase can only be done to a commit.